# git checkout -- double dash some-file is not resetting the selected file(s)

Tags: git

Let us take a look at the staged and/or modified files:

```
$git status

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitattributes
    modified:   .gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Let's attempt to roll back the changes: first start with `.gitattributes` :

```
15:52:22/ $git checkout -- .gitattributes
15:52:40/$git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:

    modified:   .gitattributes
    modified:   .gitignore
```

Comment: What is the contents of your `.gitattributes` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is pulling from Windows CRLF based files onto *Nix (macos).  CRLF is getting auto converted to LF - but that causes an "edit" to the file. `git checkout` will *also* result in that same update occurring.

I have to figure out now how to avoid the CRLF issue: but in any case the issue were not with `checkout --`